# The idea behind the regular expression r'[^\d]+'

Tags: regex, nlp

Suppose we have

```
phrase = "there are 3 numbers 34 inside 5 this sentence."
```

I don't understand why `re.findall(r'[^\d]+',phrase)` returns the following:

```
['there are ', ' numbers ', ' inside ', ' this sentence.']
```

I know that `re.findall([^\d],phrase)` returns the list of all characters except for digits and that `+`, in general, is used to find patterns with one or more occurrences, but I still don't understand how that combination returns that particular list. What is the thing whose one or more occurrences are being asked to return under `re.findall(r'[^\d]+',phrase)`?

Comment: One or more of not-digits. If you know `+` is "one or more" and `[^\d]` is "non-digit", I don't quite understand what you are unclear on, can you clarify?

Comment: Now that you say it it makes sense, I'm not sure what was blocking me to get that.. Thanks.

Comment: `re.findall(r'[^\d]+',phrase)` return all possible characters without digits. Actually, this regex split your input string at the position of digit/s. As your input string is: `there are 3 numbers 34 inside 5 this sentence.` and there are three areas where you put digit/s (3, 34 & 5). So, the regex split your string in that area. `[\d]+` means one or more digits and `[^\d]+` means one or more other input characters without digit/s. Test with regex: `re.findall(r'[\d]+',phrase)` and check what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

`[\d]` referring one digit
    `[\d]+`
    Here plus operator referring one or more occurrence of previous character.
    Since previous character being a digit[\d], it is referring one or more occurrence of digits.
    `[^\d]+`
    Here `^` referring exclude following character
    Hence exclude one or more occurrence of digits.